# Chrisjenx's Calligraphy library doesn't work

Tags: android, fonts

I don't think I really understood the ReadMe well, because I have this in my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/trado.ttf")
            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
            .build());
}

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```

And I have *trado.ttf* in my *assets* folder. This is in my `Application` class. This is all I've done, did I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Override `attachBaseContext(...)` in your `Activity`
  classes.
- Do `initDefault(...)` stuff inside `Application` `onCreate()`.
- Put `trado.ttf` inside `assets/fonts` folder.

Comment: `init` stuff?  What?

Comment: `initDefault(...)`

Answer (score 1):

```
 1. Add below code
   ViewPump.init(ViewPump.builder()
                .addInterceptor(new CalligraphyInterceptor(
                        new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                                .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf")
                                .setFontAttrId(androidx.core.R.attr.font)
                                .build()))
                .build());
 2. instead of 

   ViewPump.init(ViewPump.builder()
                .addInterceptor(new CalligraphyInterceptor(
                        new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                                .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf")
                                .setFontAttrId(R.attr.font)
```